# CRON Scheduler for OOZIE

Tags: cron, oozie, cronexpression, oozie-coordinator, crontrigger

I am working in PST timings and as per my knowledge OOZIE Coordinator jobs run in UTC time. I have no rights to change the time zone for my cluster.
My requirement is to run the workflow every first weekday every month.

Eg. If 1st april is friday it runs at 7:30 PM PST.

CRON I made - frequency = "30 2 2W * ?"

The materialized times in PST are -

```
13-31 Mar 2016 19:30:00  
12-01 Mar 2016 18:30:00
11-01 Feb 2016 18:30:00
10-31 Dec 2015 18:30:00
9-01 Dec 2015 18:30:00
8-01 Nov 2015 18:30:00
7-01 Oct 2015 19:30:00
6-01 Sep 2015 19:30:00
5-02 Aug 2015 19:30:00
4-01 Jul 2015 19:30:00
3-01 Jun 2015 19:30:00
2-30 Apr 2015 19:30:00  
1-01 Apr 2015 19:30:00
```

Now the problem is my workflow run for May 2015,Jan 2016 is skipped because 2nd May is Saturday so nearest weekday is 1st May. So it triggers at 2:30 UTC morning, converting it to PST its 31st April 2015 19:30.

Can someone give me a workaround for this...?

Comment: Can you provide your coordinator definition. The oozie coordinator can be scheduled in any time zone. Check this: [Cron][https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a4.4.3._Cron_syntax_in_coordinator_frequency]

Comment: why not using coordinator ? what have you tried ?